# I have this trigger and test class . why my test class cover 0%

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

```
trigger openTrigger on Project_Item__c (after insert,after update,after delete,after undelete) {

    Project_Item__c[] items;

    //Use Trigger.old For After Delete and The Others is Trigger.new
    if(trigger.isAfter){
        if(trigger.isDelete) items = trigger.old;
        else items = trigger.new;
    }

    //Get All Project__c (that is Id of Project) into set ids
    set <Id> ids = new set <Id>();

    for(Project_Item__c item:items){ids.add(item.Project__c);} 

    //Get Project__c , SUM (Total_Amount__c) From Project_Item__c Which Status is Open into List
    List<AggregateResult> items_ar_open= new List<AggregateResult>([Select Project__c,SUM(Total_Amount__c) from Project_Item__c where Project__c IN :ids and Status__c = 'open' Group By Project__c]);

    //Get All Project__c into array name Projects
    Project__c[] Projects = [select Id,Total_Open_custom__c,Total_Pipeline_custom__c from Project__c Where Id IN :ids]  ; 

    //Loop for getting Total_Open_custom = All Total_Amount per Project , Status OPEN
    for(Project__c Project:Projects){
        Project.Total_Open_custom__c = 0.0;

        for(AggregateResult item:items_ar_open){           
            if(Project.Id == item.get('Project__c')) {
                 Project.Total_Open_custom__c = (Decimal)item.get('expr0');
            }
        }
    }
    update Projects;
}
```

```
@isTest
private class TestClass{

    static void testUnit(){
        Project__c proj = new Project__c(Name = 'Project 001',amount__c = 100.0,close_date__c = date.ValueOf('2014-09-21'),status__c = 'open');
        insert proj;
        System.assertNotEquals(null,proj);

        Project_Item__c proItem1 = new Project_Item__c(Name = 'Item A',Project__c = proj.Id,Qty__c = 100,Status__c = 'open',description__c = 'first Item',Unit_price__c = 20);
        insert proItem1;

        Project_Item__c proItem2 = new Project_Item__c(Name = 'Item B',Project__c = proj.Id,Qty__c = 200,Status__c = 'pipeline',description__c = 'second Item',Unit_price__c = 40);
        insert proItem2;

        Project_Item__c[] proList = new Project_Item__c[]{proItem1,proItem2};

        System.assertEquals(2,proList.size()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you run the test class? Did the tests pass?

Comment: Ideally your test case should be retrieving the Project__c record and making an assertion about the Total_Open_custom__c field value.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple - you need to mark your test method with testMethod keyword:

```
static testMethod void testUnit()
```

Besides, your test code doesn't actual test your code, it just tend to get the code coverage which is a bad practice. Please don't do that.